# shared vs dynamic lib in PAM module build on OSX

Tags: macos, eclipse-cdt, mysql-connector, pam

OSX newbie here.  I have a custom PAM module that works well on RedHat.  I am trying to port it to OSX.  I've run into a wall.  I know OSX uses "OpenPam" instead of "LinuxPam".  I can actually build my module using eclipse [had to install Xcode and the Xcode command line tools though].

When I install the module and try to use it I get a generic message in the logs that just says openpam_load_module failed to load my module.  After digging on-line I found a tiny dlopen "test" program that tries to load whatever object you throw at it and if it fails gives much better errors.  My module relies on the existence of the "pam", "sqlite3" and "mysqlclient" libraries.  This test loader complains

```
   Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Well, that lib does exist.  it is in the eclipse project build path.  I have tried "hardcoding" the full path in the eclipse link line.  I have also tried linking against the static version of the lib. No joy.

If I link against the static version of the lib then I get the note:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

followed by a ton of undefined symbols.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah nuts! It is a MySQL issue.  The current Connector-C dylib was built without setting the full load path [not sure if that is the right term] for the libmysqlclient.18.dylib object inside the library.  You can use "otool -L /path/to/libmysqlclient.18.dylib"" to see the issue.  Doing some digging I found that you can use "install_name_tool" to fix the path issue... but I shouldn't have to.  I have reported the bug to MySQL